# Serialize Song class

Tags: c#, serialization, xna, media-player

I have a list of [Songs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.song.aspx). I need to store this list for loading at a later date but since there's no built in unique ID I'm just using a `KeyValuePair` that stores the track title and artist. This should be unique enough but this method alone is taking 50 seconds for 1800 tracks on a my PC. (I've updated the code. `MediaLibrary` was just for runnable code.

```
List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> kv = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>();

List<Song> chosenSongs = new List<Song>();
//...code to add to chosenSongs   

var songs = chosenSongs; 
// var songs = new MediaLibrary().Songs;

for(int i = 0; i < songs.Count; i++)
{
    kv.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(songs[i].Name, songs[i].Artist.ToString()));
}
```

This is way too slow and there's no serialization being done yet. Is there a better way of serializing objects of type Song?

Comment: Why do you need to serialise the songs? Are you sure it's adding to the list that takes the time, i'd expect it to be the call to `MediaLibrary().Songs`, especially if there are a lot.

Comment: Are you sure that the bad performance are being caused when adding the `KeyValuePair` to `List`?

Comment: If it's taking 50s to do that; it's likely because the application is reading that information from disk. There is no way creating a list of 1800 KVPs in memory would take 50s.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett - The user can create a playlist of Songs. As far I can see, there is no way to allow the user to save this playlist (which is a list of Songs). The example above was just something that was runnable but in reality `MediaLibrary().Songs` won't be used. (I'll update question to make that clearer)

Comment: Note that according to MSDN a `SongsCollection` (which the `Songs` method returns) is lazy, meaning it doesn't load the songs until you request them. So it might be the `new KeyValuePair` line that is slow, but only because you're accessing the song (i.e. it's not the inserting to the list that's slow, it's accessing the song).

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett - Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: How does the user create their list of songs, could you add the keyvalue pair one at a time as the user chooses them (that way the delay of loading the song to get name and artist isn't all in one go)?

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett - The initial idea was that the user can bulk select (mouse drag similar to Explorer) to select the songs. But now you've pointed out that the lazy loading could be the issue, I might have to simply change that way of selecting songs.

Comment: If they are bulk selecting, then don't you already have the names of the songs to display? Can't you create the keyvalue ready to add then? I don't see how what you're doing to make a list for users to select is different to your example above.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett - Well this is embarrassing. Because the form was different, I was essentially recreating instantiating the songs twice (once to display it and once again when that list is passed to a new form). Been working on this code too long :D Thanks for your help, I'll just move the point at which the pair is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are getting various properties of `Song`s. I'm fairly sure this cause a disk read on the PC (at best, you could've selected a network media library), which is fundamentally going to be slow when you've got thousands to go through.

Your best bet is to try and structure the UI so that work is spread out, i.e. load each song's information as the user selects it / as you need to display it.